# CSS :after pseudo element, working in Chrome, doesn't work in Edge

Tags: css

Below CSS is working perfect in Chrome but not in edge I tried `::after` it doesn't make any difference.
I also tried `position: visible` and `hidden`, but no luck.

```
    input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]+label {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      overflow: visible;
      padding: 9px;
      top: 4px;
      border: 2px solid $border-contrast-dark;
      border-radius: 50%;
      left: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
      background-color: $action-success-color;
      color: $text-contrast-light;
      border: 2px solid $border-contrast-light;
    }

    // its not taking below properties
    input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      left: 3px;
      top: 0px;
      color: white; // its not taking this property
      content: '\2714';
      @include font-size(14px);
    }
```

Comment: Provide your HTML too. Also, you tagged the question with `internet-explorer` but write "Edge" in the text, so which is it?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion but its being solved now.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the question need to be at a certain standard if it should have a reasonable value for future users, and it doesn't as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > // its not taking below properties

CSS does not support commening with `//` like JS does.
So remove comments like this (or replace them with `/* comment */` if needed)

2. > its not taking this property

That's because Edge renders your `\2714` as emoji symbol (because it can).
You have to apply a trick to fix it. See the snippet below:

```css
    input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]+label {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      overflow: visible;
      padding: 9px;
      top: 4px;
      border: 2px solid $border-contrast-dark;
      border-radius: 55%;
      left: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
      background-color: grey;
      color: white;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
 
    input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      left: 3px;
      top: 0px;
      color: white;
      font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol"; /* for Edge */
      content: '\2714\fe0e'; /* \fe0e for Safari and others */
      @include font-size(14px);
    }
```

```html
<input id="i" type="checkbox">
<label for ="i">Label</label>
```